# Delete Label underline

Tags: ionic-framework

So my problem is that under my label i have an underline that i want to delete. i added no-lines to my ion-label but it's seems to not working.

Is there a way to delete it ?

```
<ion-item class="checkbox" >
  <ion-label></ion-label>
  <ion-checkbox class="checkbox-square" (ionChange)="changeEvent($event)"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

And this is the css

```
.checkbox{
    font-size: 1.03rem;
    color: $blue-love;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your css

```
.checkbox .item-inner {
    border-bottom: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without touching the CSS: This worked out for me
https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/html/how+to+remove+the+underline+from+ion+item

TLDR;

```
 <ion-item lines="none">
        <ion-tags...>
 </ion-item>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add *custom class* inside `ion-label` element:

```
<ion-label class="custom-label-style">
  Label content
</ion-label>
```

Then style it with `text-decoration` property:

```
.custom-label-style {
  text-decoration: none;
};
```